# python: DataFrame.append does not append element

Tags: python, pandas

I am working one week with python and I need some help.
I want that if certain condition is fulfilled, it adds a value to a database.
My program doesn't give an error but it doesn't append an element to my database

```
import pandas as pd
noTEU = pd.DataFrame() # empty database
index_TEU = 0
for vessel in list:
    if condition is fullfilled:
        imo_vessel = pd.DataFrame({'imo': vessel}, index=[index_TEU])   
        noTEU.append(imo_vessel) # I want here to add an element to my database
        index_TEU = index_TEU + 1
```

If I run this, at the end I still get an empty dataframe. I have no idea why it doesn't do what I want it to do

Comment: It is not an inplace operation. Try `noTEU = noTEU.append(imo_vessel)`

Comment: Do we have a canonical question for this? Not specific to append but in general, for methods returning a new dataframe?

Comment: @ayhan there are a ton of questions with the same answer but there isn't a canonical one, it should be created as it gets tiresome explaining this

Comment: There's a similar one asked over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597265/appending-to-an-empty-data-frame-in-pandas

Comment: @NickilMaveli yeah that might be a good target for this question but I don't know if we could use it if the question was about, say, drop instead of append. It might be better if someone posted a general question about this.

Comment: @ayhan: Totally agree with that. Even the docs don't indicate whether `append` operation takes place `inplace` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reassign the dataframe such as:

```
import pandas as pd
noTEU = pd.DataFrame() # empty database
index_TEU = 0
for vessel in list:
    if condition is fullfilled:
        imo_vessel = pd.DataFrame({'imo': vessel}, index=[index_TEU])   
        noTEU = noTEU.append(imo_vessel) # I want here to add an element to my database
        index_TEU = index_TEU + 1
```

and don't use the keyword `list` for a List because it's included in the Python syntax.