# Pandas: Function fails to append data frame to empty data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I'm scraping property ads with BS4, using pandas for analysis.
Using multiprocessing, I have the following,

```
def show_ad_prices(options):
    pool = Pool(options)

    page_link_list=[] # list of urls of pages with ads
    BS4_main(page_root_url) # BS4_main requests and parses url
    last_page_number=int(container.findAll("a", href=re.compile('^('+house_href+')((?!:).)*$'))[-2].text)
    for i in range(1,last_page_number):
       page_nr=page_root_url+'pagina-'+str(i)+'.htm'    
       page_link_list.append(page_nr)

    for page_link_url in page_link_list:
       overall_df=pd.DataFrame() 
       print(page_link_url)
       ad_page_urls = get_ad_page_urls(page_link_url) # returns all urls of ads on one page

       try:
           results = pool.map(get_ad_data, ad_page_urls) # gets data from ad 
       except Exception:
           print('error: '+page_link_url)
           continue

       try:
           df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(results) # make DataFrame of data of all ads of one page
           print(df)
           overall_df.append(df) # append DataFrame to overall DataFrame
           print(total_df)
       except Exception: 
           print('error: '+page_link_url)

     return overall_df
```

My code successfully creates a dataframe of all ads on **one** page. `print(df)` prints such a "one-page" dataframe. However, when I try to append a one-page dataframe to the empty overall dataframe, nothing happens. The overall dataframe stays empty.

I've tried the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597265/appending-to-an-empty-data-frame-in-pandas), but it doesn't seem to work. The could should be creating a one-page DataFrame and subsequently append this to the overall DataFrame.

Comment: I believe the culprit is `for page_link_url in page_link_list: overall_df=pd.DataFrame()`. `overall_df` is initialized to an empty dataframe every iteration. Try to move `overall_df=pd.DataFrame()` outside the loop. Also keep in mind your issue might be that every process has it's own `overall_df` variable in memory. You'll need to post the rest of the code if that is the case.

Comment: Also, `append` is not an inplace operation for DataFrames so you'll need to reassign, i.e. `overall_df = overall_df.append(df)`.

Comment: `.append()` does not happen in-place.  You need to reassign to the data frame variable as @root indicated

Comment: Thanks so much guys, it's working!