# Initializing a class with a pandas DataFrame and filling it

Tags: python, pandas, class

I'm trying to create a class which inherits a pandas DataFrame, with some modifications. However, it did not work as expected.

```
import pandas as pd
class result(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, x):
        pd.DataFrame.__init__(self)
        j = pd.DataFrame({'a': x})
        print(x)
        print(j)
        self.append(j)
```

The result:

```
>>> k = result([2,4])
[2, 4]
   a
0  2
1  4
>>> print(k)
Empty result
Columns: []
Index: []
```

As you can see, somehow the returned value is not appended by `j`. For comparison, observe when `j` and `k` are not defined within the class:

```
>>> k = pd.DataFrame()
>>> j = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2,4]})
>>> print(k.append(j))
   a
0  2
1  4
```

What causes the difference? What should I write within `result` if I want the arguments `x` to be appended into `j`?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: what should be the value of k here?

Comment: It should be a pd.DataFrame with a = [2,4].

Comment: please edit the question and provide the expected output in right format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that `append` doesn't happen in-place, so you'll have to store the output. You can find an example in here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597265/appending-to-an-empty-data-frame-in-pandas) 
For in this case, you can do something like that:

```
import pandas as pd


class Result:

  def __init__(self):
      self.main_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=['a'])

  def append_dataset(self, x):
      temp_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=x, columns=['a'])
      self.main_dataframe = self.main_dataframe.append(temp_dataframe)

  def debug(self):
      print(self.main_dataframe)
      # a
      # 0  2
      # 1  4


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      k = Result()
      k.append_dataset(x=[2, 4])
      k.debug()
```

**How to inherit Pandas class**
    More information in here [Inheriting Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/extending.html#extending-subclassing-pandas)

```
import pandas as pd

class Result(pd.DataFrame):

  @property
  def _constructor(self):
      return Result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    k = Result(data=[2, 4], columns=['a'])
    tem_data = pd.DataFrame(data=[5, 6], columns=['a'])
    k = k.append(tem_data)
    print(k)
```

Comment: Thanks @Aybars. Is there a way to keep the inheritance strucutre? i.e. so that Result inherits from pd.DataFrame?

Comment: @TimMak, yes, you can. I have updated my answer. I hope it will help. You can find more information about it at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/extending.html#extending-subclassing-pandas

Comment: @TimMak, if the post answers your question, please accept it as a solution.

Comment: I think I have.