# Efficient solutions insert or update row pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
              0               1   2
 0   0.00086076    500.00000000  []
 1   0.00086075    819.00000000  []
 2   0.00086072   1162.00000000  []
 3   0.00086071     20.00000000  []
 4   0.00086069  10170.00000000  []
 5   0.00086067     18.00000000  []
```

Then I have another dataframe with update values:

```
              0               1   2
 0   0.00086071     50.00000000  []
 1   0.00086068     81.00000000  []
```

It is sorted on column 0 and I need to merge the two as follows:

```
              0               1   2
 0   0.00086076    500.00000000  []
 1   0.00086075    819.00000000  []
 2   0.00086072   1162.00000000  []
 3   0.00086071     50.00000000  []
 4   0.00086069  10170.00000000  []
 5   0.00086068     81.00000000  []
 6   0.00086067     18.00000000  []
```

So if a value matches one in column 0 it should update column 1 if not it should insert a new row and sort again.

Is there an efficient way or predefined function for doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you need:

- [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) both `DataFrame`s together
- [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for remove original rows with same values in column `0`
- [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by column `0`
- [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for unique index values

---

```
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
        .drop_duplicates([0] , keep='last')
        .sort_values(0 , ascending=False)
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
          0        1   2
0  0.000861    500.0  []
1  0.000861    819.0  []
2  0.000861   1162.0  []
3  0.000861     50.0  []
4  0.000861  10170.0  []
5  0.000861     81.0  []
6  0.000861     18.0  []
```

Comment: Is your `df[0]` all the same, as you posted? If so, then it isn't like the desired output.

Comment: @jo9k He is just printing them with less precision. The information is there nevertheless

Comment: This implementation throws away the original duplicate row, so in the more general case where `df2` contains only the columns you want to update (assuming there are more columns in `df1`), it will erase the other values in the original duplicate row that aren't being updated.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is  [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)  and [drop duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
df = df1.append(df2)
df = df.drop_duplicates('0', keep='last').sort_values('0', ascending= False)
```

But according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15822811)
Jezrael answer is the fast and most efficient mine is just an alternative !

Comment: I think it is not so nice copy my solution :(