# How to concat dataframes so missing values are set to NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes df1 and df2.   Here is a toy example so show my question. `df1` looks like

```
col1 col2
1    2
0    7
```

`df2` looks like

```
col1 col3
9    2
5    3
```

I would like to do `pd.concat([df1,df2])` but in such a way that the result is:

```
col1 col2 col3
1    2    NaN
0    7    Nan
9    NaN  2
5    NaN  3
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['col1'] = [1, 0]
df1['col2'] = [2, 7]

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['col1'] = [9, 5]
df2['col3'] = [5, 3]

x = df1.append(df2)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1   2.0   NaN
1     0   7.0   NaN
0     9   NaN   5.0
1     5   NaN   3.0
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I made a silly mistake missing the [].  How is append different from concat?

Comment: This would be a good read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819050/pandas-dataframe-concat-vs-append

Comment: Another link to understand append, concatenation and merge concepts in Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html