# Already use pd.concat but still trigger "PerformanceWarning: Dataframe is highly fragmented"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, warnings

I met a strange behavior in Python pandas. To prevent the "Dataframe is highly fragmented" warning, I already use pd.concat. But after that, when I add one more column in the concatted dataframe, the warning might show up in some cases.

Case a: Concat one empty df with many series. Then add one more column. Warning.

Case b: Concat many series then add one more column. It's fine.

Case c: Concat many dfs then add one more column. Warning.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

print(sys.version)  # 3.8.11
print('pandas version: ',pd.__version__)  # pandas version:  2.0.3

list_of_series = [pd.Series([1,2,3]) for i in range(200)]

a = pd.DataFrame()
a = pd.concat([a]+list_of_series,axis=1)
a['one_more_col'] = [4,5,6]  # concating one df with many series incurs warning

b = pd.concat(list_of_series,axis=1)
b['one_more_col'] = [4,5,6]  # concating series only. It's fine.

c = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in list_of_series],axis=1,)
c['one_more_col'] = [4,5,6]  # concating many dataframes incurs warning
```

Now I have two questions:

1. Why does this happen?
2. If I have a concatted dataframe and I want to add more columns, what should I do? Use pd.concat once more?

BTW, my question is different from this one. [PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented. This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68292862/performancewarning-dataframe-is-highly-fragmented-this-is-usually-the-result-o)

In that question, using pd.concat can prevent the warning. But in my question, I already used pd.concat and after that, adding one more column incurs the warning in case a and c.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented. This is usually the result of calling \`frame.insert\` many times, which has poor performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68292862/performancewarning-dataframe-is-highly-fragmented-this-is-usually-the-result-o)

Comment: @bb1 Maybe not. Cause I have already used pd.concat which is recommended in the link.

Comment: The second recommendation for de-fragmention  in the warning _"To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`"_ actually helps. (But that doesn't answer the legit question regarding the difference in cases `a`/`c` and `b`.)

Answer (score 0):

In case a, you are concating a dataframe with a list of series. It will keep a reference to the dataframe a that could be modified :

```
a = pd.DataFrame()
new_a = pd.concat([a]+list_of_series,axis=1)
```

Then a and new_a are share same data, you should avoid this.

Consider using assign to add new colums :

```
a = pd.concat(list_of_series,axis=1)
a = a.assign(one_more_col= pd.Series([4,5,6]))
```

It will also work in case b and c.