# Python performance warning using dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have inherited a long code in a project and I am getting this performance error:

> PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy() df['xcount'] = df.apply(self.gocountwords_complex, axis=1)`

The line that is generating the error is this:

```
df['xcount'] = df.apply(self.go_unigram, axis=1)
df[self.listsunigram] = pd.DataFrame(df.xcount.tolist(), index=df.index)

df['xcount'] = df.apply(self.go_bigram, axis=1)
df[self.listsbigram] = pd.DataFrame(df.xcount.tolist(), index=df.index)

df['xcount'] = df.apply(self.go_complex, axis=1)
df[self.listcomplex] = pd.DataFrame(df.xcount.tolist(), index=df.index)
```

where

1. `self.listsunigram`/`self.listsbigram`/`self.listcomplex` is a list with several column names (not all columns in the df)
2. `xcount` is a list with several values returned by a function

The idea is that every value in `xcount` is assigned to a column in `df[self.listsunigram]` (and the remaining 2)

I would like to fix this but I have no idea how, any help?

Comment: It is not an error it is a warning. Is the performance of that line of code an issue?
If not can it become an issue in the future? Others have also gotten this warning but if the performance of the code is not issue, it is save to [ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68292862/performancewarning-dataframe-is-highly-fragmented-this-is-usually-the-result-o) the warning.

Also without knowing what the self.go_unigram and self.go_bigram or self.go_complex methods look like we can not really give an answer on how to solve the warning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented. This is usually the result of calling \`frame.insert\` many times, which has poor performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68292862/performancewarning-dataframe-is-highly-fragmented-this-is-usually-the-result-o)

Comment: self.go_unigram and self.go_bigram or self.go_complex run some procedures and return a list with 20 elements and n rows, the number of rows is the same as in the original DF, so it adds a column called xcount, which is then "unpacked" to several columns. this is what is creating the error.

Comment: @Laurent that seems to have fixed it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting these warnings because you are repeatedly **inserting** columns into your dataframe instead of **concatenating** them together, which is much more efficient memory wise.

For instance, running this toy code:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({f"col{i}": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] for i in range(1_000)})

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1_000):  # insert one thousand columns
    new_df[f"new_df_col{i}"] = df[f"col{i}"]+i

print(new_df)
```

You will get this output:

> PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
> new_df[f"new_df_col{i}"] = df[f"col{i}"]+i

```
   new_df_col0  new_df_col1  new_df_col2  ...  new_df_col998  new_df_col999
0            0            1            2  ...            998            999
1            1            2            3  ...            999           1000
2            2            3            4  ...           1000           1001
3            3            4            5  ...           1001           1002
4            4            5            6  ...           1002           1003
5            5            6            7  ...           1003           1004
6            6            7            8  ...           1004           1005
7            7            8            9  ...           1005           1006
8            8            9           10  ...           1006           1007
9            9           10           11  ...           1007           1008

[10 rows x 1000 columns]
```

Whereas, for instance, initializing an empty dictionary instead of a dataframe, and using Pandas [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({f"col{i}": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] for i in range(1_000)})

data = {}
for i in range(1_000):
    data[f"new_col{i}"] = df[f"col{i}"] + i

new_df = pd.concat(data.values(), axis=1, ignore_index=True)
new_df.columns = data.keys()  # since Python 3.7, order of insertion is preserved

print(new_df)
```

You will get the same dataframe without any warning:

```
   new_col0  new_col1  new_col2  new_col3  ...  new_col997  new_col998  new_col999
0         0         1         2         3  ...         997         998         999
1         1         2         3         4  ...         998         999        1000
2         2         3         4         5  ...         999        1000        1001
3         3         4         5         6  ...        1000        1001        1002
4         4         5         6         7  ...        1001        1002        1003
5         5         6         7         8  ...        1002        1003        1004
6         6         7         8         9  ...        1003        1004        1005
7         7         8         9        10  ...        1004        1005        1006
8         8         9        10        11  ...        1005        1006        1007
9         9        10        11        12  ...        1006        1007        1008

[10 rows x 1000 columns]
```

So, try refactoring your code by replacing:

```py
df[self.listsunigram] = pd.DataFrame(df.xcount.tolist(), index=df.index)
```

with:

```py
df = pd.concat(
    [df, pd.DataFrame(df.xcount.tolist(), index=df.index, columns=self.listsunigram)],
    axis=1,
)
```

And do the same thing for the other statements.