# How do I use pd.concat when I get this error "PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented"?

Tags: python, pandas

I´m trying to predict the next game of an NBA team from a csv file. For that I want to add a new row to the file which indicates if the team won or lost the their next game.

This is the error im getting:

PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`

This is the function I wrote to get a new row which shows if the team won or lost their next game.

```
def add_target(group):
    group["target"] = group["won"].shift(-1)
    return group

df = df.groupby("team", group_keys=False).apply(add_target)
```

Comment: Please add a sample of your data

Comment: Try replacing the code snippet you've shared with this line: `df['target'] = df.groupby('team', group_keys=False)['won'].shift(-1)`

Comment: Where are you using `pd.concat()`? Is it in a loop? If so, that may be the issue.

Comment: @gtomer how do I do that? (sorry im new to coding)

Comment: @rasputin I dont use `pd.concat()` and `df['target'] = df.groupby('team', group_keys=False)['won'].shift(-1)` is not working either unfortunately

Comment: Have you read through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68292862/performancewarning-dataframe-is-highly-fragmented-this-is-usually-the-result-o)? It gives a few options for fixing or suppressing the warning. Have you tried adding `df = df.copy()` right before the warning?