# Replacing append with concat?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation

Whenever I run this code I get:

The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
What should I do to make the code run with concat?

```
final_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns = my_columns)
for symbol in stocks['Ticker']:
    api_url = f'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{symbol}/quote?token={IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN}'
    data = requests.get(api_url).json()
    final_dataframe = final_dataframe.append(
                                        pd.Series([symbol, 
                                                   data['latestPrice'], 
                                                   data['marketCap'], 
                                                   'N/A'], 
                                                  index = my_columns), 
                                        ignore_index = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this release note](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append)

or from another post:

> "Append is the specific case(axis=0, join='outer') of concat" [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51436106/15521392)

The changes in your code should be: (changed the `pd.Series` to variable just for presentation)

```
s = pd.Series([symbol, data['latestPrice'], data['marketCap'], 'N/A'], index = my_columns)
final_dataframe = pd.concat([final_dataframe, s], ignore_index = True)
```