# Union Multiple Dataframes with different structure in Python without Key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, union

I would like to union multiple Dataframes with different structure in Python without a key.

Example: Input dataframes as below

**DF1**

| col1 | col2 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | aaa | bbb |
| bcd | bbb | ccc |

**DF2**

| col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cde | ccc | ddd |
| def | ddd | eee |

**Result should be:
DF3**

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | aaa | bbb | --- | --- | --- |
| bcd | bbb | ccc | --- | --- | --- |
| --- | --- | --- | cde | ccc | ddd |
| --- | --- | --- | def | ddd | eee |

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to do row bind.
You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([df1, df2]))
```

**or** you can use this:

```
output = df1.append(df2)
```

**Update:**

First match and convert the data types to match other data frame:

```
df2 = df2.astype(df1.dtypes.to_dict())
```

and then do this

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]))
```

You can also use this one liner if you have same columns in both

```
df2.astype(df1.dtypes).append(df2)
```

This is a possible duplicate of [Pandas version of rbind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988480/pandas-version-of-rbind)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. How can we handle with mixed types while doing union?

Example: Column b in DF1 is Int but Column b in DF2 is String
While concatenating the above column from both datasets, it is throwing below error
"pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: ("Expected bytes, got a 'int' object", 'Conversion failed for column b with type object')"

Much appreciate your help :)

Comment: @MaheshDonthireddy You need to convert the data types of one data frame to match the other and then row bind it.

Comment: Thanks again!     

In our case, we are dealing with close to thousands of columns, so I guess I might need to loop through each merged/concatenated dataframe and assign it's data type to the new dataframe. I imagine it might make the things complicated.    

Kindly suggest :)

Comment: @MaheshDonthireddy Check my updated answer, I have added one liner solution if you have same columns in both the data frames.

Comment: @RushabPatel The above syntax was throwing error. I had to implement looping mechanism to check common columns dtype and assign string if dtype doesn't match.
I know it is costly operation.
Please let me know if you come across an easy solution for this problem in future.

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement looping mechanism to check common columns dtype and assign string if dtype doesn't match. It works fine for time-being. Please post here if anyone come across an easy solution for this problem in future.